# AVR Attiy45 PWM Servo motor control in Assembly

Tags: avr, pwm, servo, assembly

I'm trying to contol a servo motor with attiny45 writing the code in assembler. I figured out how to set the timer in pwm mode and how to choose a needed prescaler. And with different OCR0A values i'm getting the neutral and 0 degrees position. However, i've ran into a problem with 180 degrees. When I keep the timer settings the same and don't set the OCR0A, the servo easily goes to 180 degrees. But when i change the OCR0A to get different pulse and different motor positions and than try to come back to default OCR0A value, nothing works. So, the code:

This puts my motor in 180 degrees position

```
.includepath "/usr/share/avra/"
.device ATtiny45 
.DEF A=R16

.equ DDRB = 0x17
.equ PORTB = 0x18 
.equ TCCR0A = 0x2A
.equ TCCR0B = 0x33
.equ OCR0A = 0x29
.ORG $0000
SBI DDRB, 0x3
SBI PORTB, 0x3
ON_RESET:
    SBI DDRB, 0
    LDI A, 0b10000011
    OUT TCCR0A, A
    LDI A, 0b00000011
    OUT TCCR0B,A
MAIN_LOOP:
    RJMP MAIN_LOOP
```

This doesn't (Hope it's easy to understand what I'm trying to do here)

```
.includepath "/usr/share/avra/"
.device ATtiny45
.DEF A=R16

.equ DDRB = 0x17
.equ PORTB = 0x18
.equ TCCR0A = 0x2A
.equ TCCR0B = 0x33
.equ OCR0A = 0x29
.ORG $0000
SBI DDRB, 0x3
SBI PORTB, 0x3

ON_RESET:
    SBI DDRB, 0
    LDI A, 0b10000011
    OUT TCCR0A, A
    LDI A, 0b00000011
    OUT TCCR0B,A
MAIN_LOOP:
    LDI A, 0xFF
    OUT OCR0A, A
    RCALL DELAY_05
    RCALL DELAY_05
    RCALL DELAY_05
    RCALL DELAY_05
    LDI A, 192
    OUT OCR0A, A
    RCALL DELAY_05
    RCALL DELAY_05
    RCALL DELAY_05
    RCALL DELAY_05
    LDI A, 40
    OUT OCR0A, A
    RCALL DELAY_05
    RCALL DELAY_05
    RCALL DELAY_05
    RCALL DELAY_05
    RJMP MAIN_LOOP

DELAY_05:
    LDI R17,8
OUTER_LOOP:
    LDI R24, low(3037)
    LDI R25, high(3037)
DELAY_LOOP:
    ADIW R24,1
    BRNE DELAY_LOOP
    DEC R17
    BRNE OUTER_LOOP
    RET
```

Yes i don't know how to write a 2 sec. delay function.

So is there a way to 'reset' the OCR0A register?

Comment: Just curious, why did you choose to program in assembler?

Comment: @jippie Because it's fun. And i feel like i have a clearer idea of what's going on. I'll switch to C when I'll be confident with basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this is solved. Stupidly easy. The default OCR0A value is 0.